# Deleting duplicates of plus or minus symbolic quantities from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Let's say I have a list `l = {a + bc - d, -a - bc + d, a + b};`. Now I want to apply `DeleteDuplicates[l, crit]` to this list, such that the criterion `crit` considers first and second elements in the list as equal, so one of them is dropped. The first and the second element in the list differ only by an overall sign. Of course, entries that are completely identical should also still be recognized as duplicates. What should the criterion be to accomplish this?

Comment: Does `Simplify[Abs[#1] == Abs[#2]]&` do what you want?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Partrick Stevens suggested in his comment, `Simplify[Abs[#1] == Abs[#2]]&` can be used as the criterion.

```
DeleteDuplicates[{
  b + a, a + b c - d, -a - b c + d, a + b}, 
  Simplify[Abs[#1] == Abs[#2]]&]
```

> ```
> {a + b, a + b c - d}
> ```